# How can I modify my print_list to be in brackets to look like [1, 2, 3]?

Tags: python

*there is other code that I've not included bc I think its not relevant*

What I have:

```
def print_list(node):
    print('[', end=" ")

    while node:
        print(node)
        if node.next:
            print(',', end=" ")
        node = node.next

    print(']')
```

I am getting an output of:

```
[ 1
, 2
, 3
]
```

it is fixed now, for anyone who wants the corrected version here
thank you JohanC(:

```
def print_list(node):
    print('[', end="")
    while node:
        print(node, end="")
        if node.next:
            print(',', end=" ")
        node = node.next
    print(']')


print_list(node1)
```

Comment: And what is the output you are expecting?

Comment: what do u mean by being in brackets?

Comment: wild guess here but are you looking for `print(", ".join([str(n) for n in node]))`? Show us what input you are passing to your function.

Comment: `print([1,2,3])` will give you `[1, 2, 3]`. what else do you want?

Comment: change your ```print(node)``` to ```print(node, end = " ")``` i guess?

Comment: Why are you doing `print('[', end=" ")` and not just `print('[ ')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you also don't want a newline after `print(node)` ?

```
def print_list(node):
    print('[', end="")

    while node:
        print(node, end="")
        if node.next:
            print(',', end=" ")
        node = node.next

    print(']')
```

Note that `print('something')` prints out the given text and then starts a new line. `print(']', end=' ')` doesn't start a new line, but instead prints out the string given by `end=`, which can be an empty string.

Comment: This will be `[ 1 , 2 , 3 ]` not `[1, 2, 3]`.